# Changing wordpress URL - domain and server are in different providers

Tags: wordpress, cross-domain, dreamhost

I have a problem with changing my **WordPress URL**.

I got my WordPress site installed on a **Dreamhost server** with an address for example **www.test123.com/s1**

And I got my domain parked with a different provider and there I have a domain named **www.training.com**.

I want to change **WordPress URL** to show **www.training.com** as of now its **www.test123.com/s1** so I can access this website through only **www.training.com** address.

I changed the **WordPress URL**, and A record in DNS settings on **www.training.com** to point to Dreamhost server where WordPress is installed but I still get **"Website not found"** but at least with a Dreamhost screen. So I guess A record is pointing to the good server but there is something else I forgot.

I'll be glad for any answer or help.

Comment: Sometimes it just takes a little while, sometimes a few hours depending on provider, for the DNS to propagate.  Give it a little time.

Answer (score 1):

You've done the right thing with pointing www.training.com to your dreamhost server.  All DNS changes may require 4-24 hours to take effect or to propagate to your local computer.  If you're getting website not found, you probably just need to wait for this to happen.

I usually like to check what the site looks at in other locations with geopeeker.com .  geopeeker will likely show what your site will look like using the new DNS record.

Also, in your wordpress database, if you have access, there should be two places where the URL is stored.  One is called siteurl, the other homeurl or something like that.  If you have problems after the DNS has propagated, you can try double checking those records to make sure they're pointing to www.training.com.